# Use tuple-returning Python function in another function call

Tags: python

I'm trying to do something like this in my code:

```
def fu():
    return np.array([1,2,3]), np.array([4,5,6])

def bar(x,y,z):
    print np.size(x)
    print np.size(y)
    print np.size(z)

bar(np.array([7,8]), fu())
```

but I'm getting an error message saying `bar() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)`. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
bar(np.array([7,8]), *fu())
```

([unpack](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) the tuple returned by `fu()`)

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

def fu():
   return np.array([1,2,3]), np.array([4,5,6])

def bar(x,y,z):
   print np.size(x)
   print np.size(y)
   print np.size(z)

bar(np.array([7,8]), *fu())

--output:--
2
3
3
```

Comment: How is this different than my answer?

Comment: @arshajii, I'm sorry, I didn't receive any telepathic warnings that you were answering the question at the same time I was.  Did you send them?

Comment: You answered two minutes later, so I assumed I didn't need to send any telepathic warnings. In any case, I don't mean to be confrontational, just doing my part to keep the bowels of the inter-webs clutter-free.